# how to make a dashboard and query in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

I am new in splunk and only have a basic knowledge in querying. I need to create a dashboard that will count the total number of policy for each server. I have an example data, it shows the different host and policy.

Example data:

[image]

I want to generate a dashboard like this:
[image]

My code is like this:

```
eval search if("$Host$"="AAA") | stats count(Policy) as "AAA" by Policy |
eval search if("$Host$"="BBB") | stats count(Policy) as "BBB" by Policy |
eval search if("$Host$"="CCC") | stats count(Policy) as "CCC" by Policy |
```

Answer (score 2):

`stats` is a filtering command so Host values are lost to subsequent `eval` statements.  Try this query, instead:

```
... | stats count by Host, Policy | addcoltotals
```